# Implicit declaration of function 'LogTrace' is invalid in C99?

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I am developing an IOS app in Xcode 5 and getting this error "**Implicit declaration of  function 'LogTrace' is invalid in C99**". Can anyone suggest me what may be the reason for this?

```
NSArray *arr = [temporaryContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
reccount = [arr count];
if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
    LogTrace(@"Error in getsize - error:%@",[error userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: Show the code of your LogTrace (at least what's before and after the {}.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have LogTrace defined in a header that is not included in the current file. You should find the header that defines it and ensure it is with your `#import` directives.